# Is this a normal amount of sap from an apricot tree after pruning?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care, apricots, sap

My apricot tree is secreting what seems to me as copious amounts of sap. Is this a normal amount of sap after pruning about a year ago, or is my tree sick?

[image]

Comment: I would like to know what kind of pruning cut you made. What angle is that, downward? Did you prune back to a node (joining place)(good) or leave a stump (bad)? Did you prune an upward tending branch (good) or a weak downward one (should have pruned back further or cut the upward branch.)

Comment: The angle of cut is straight. I left a small stump on a downward branch. Is this a bad cut? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

it really looks like that tree is sufferring from too much water.
I'm not sure where you are from but did you get a lot of rainfall this year?
If so this can definately be the cause of all this sap, that much is definately not normal.
Ensure that you are not providing additional water and that there is adequate drainage for this tree other wise you will notice the branches begin to die out.

It also depends on where the sap is coming from, I cant really tell from the picture, it looks like you cut out a huge branch?  Do you have holes in the actual tree from say woodpeckers?
More details would help.

Good luck

Comment: (1) Yes, we had a good rainfall this winter. I didn't water the tree during the rainy season, but I am watering a lot now. (2) How can I check the tree's drainage? (3) The tree is only 6 years old, but the branch was one of the bigger ones. (4) No woodpeckers, but I did notice ants gathering around what seemed to be open sores under some branches.